# Second Order Circuit, Sadiku's Fundamentals of Electric Circuits

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I would like some help with Sadiku's exercise about second order circuits.

I did'nt understand why the solution says that V (0) = -30 V.

Also, I did not understand why the capacitor's voltage (Vc) is -30 V.

Isn't the voltage for t <0  (when the capacitor is loaded) the same as the voltage source?[image]

The exercise asked i(t) for t>0 . The switch opens at t=0 after a long time closed.

[image]

---

If I change to + - in the capacitor as suggested.

For t<0: V(0)= 30 V and i(0)= 15 A

For t>0:

α= R/(2L)= 2/(2*0,5)= 2

omega = 1/sqrt (LC) = 1/sqrt(0.5*0.25) = 2.82942712475

Under-damped:

di/dt= -2(15 cos(2t)+ B sin(2t))e^-2t + (-2*15 sin (2t) + 2 Bcos(2t))e^2t

di(0)/dt = -30+ 2B = -(1/L) [R*i(o)+ Vc(0)] = -2 [30+30] = -120

-30+2B=-120

B= -45

i(t)= 15 cos (2t) + (-45 sin (2t))e^-2t A

So, the answer isn't the same as the book's solution.

Comment: When googling Sadiku, only football guys are coming up. Are we supposed to know who it is?

Comment: Sorry, it's a famous book on Eletrical Engeneering graduation.
It's called Fundamentals of Electric Circuits, 5th edition by Matthew Sadiku

Comment: Why do you think the answer is wrong? What is your version? The capacitor is fully charged initially, so it's voltage equals to the one of the power supply. Since the polarity of it is defined opposite to the one of the supply, it has the negative sign.

Comment: According to my researches the voltage at the capacitor is the same as the voltage source if the capacitor is loaded. 

So, V(0) for t<0 should be equal to 30 V. (Voltage Source).

Also the capacitor should have 30 V, and the solution book says that the voltage Vc(0) = -30 V.

Comment: Have you read my *whole* comment? Vc is defined in opposite polarity than the supply, as shown on the second drawing.

Comment: In the exercise there is no polarity defined in the capacitor, only in the solutions.

Comment: This is up to you how you define it. It will not change the answer. They ask for current, not voltage.

Comment: If V(0)= 30 V, and Vc (0)= 30 V  i(t) won't change?

Comment: No, it won't if you keep it consistent through the calculation (start with swapping + and - for Vc on your version of the equivalent circuit). You are very welcome to try and convince yourself.

Comment: I found B=-45.  And i(t)=(15 cos(2t) + (-45 sin (2t) e^-2t)

Comment: There cannot possibly be a steady-state sinusoid in the response, so your solution is wrong

Comment: @Chu could you please explain it to me? 

Do you think that V (0) = -30 V and Vc(0)= -30 V ?

Comment: Sort out the brackets - the 15cos(2t) term is not multiplied by the exponential term. The assumed polarity of Vc(0) is not given in the diagram, so it's impossible to say. You may choose either, but you must formulate the equations based on your chosen polarity and the current direction already specified in the diagram. If the actual polarity turns out to be opposite to the one you've chosen, the value of Vc(0) will be negative.The maths will sort out the correct polarity, just don't change track half way through the analysis.

Comment: ... but the *solution* has assumed that the positive end of Vc is to the right...